# How can I get the default value of the first parameter without sending it while calling

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I want to get the output in this way,

```
Lucifer is 20 years old
Default is 20 years old
```

the problem is that if I send an empty string as first argument and 20 as the second, I get the following output:

```
Lucifer is 20 years old
is 20 years old
```

And again if I send only one parameter say 20 as the first parameter and no second parameter, I get the following output:

```
Lucifer is 20 years old
20 is 20 years old
```

Here is my code and the constructor is the function I am sending parameters to:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name = 'Default',age=0){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    getDescription() {
        return `${this.name} is ${this.age} years old`
    }
}

const me = new Person('Lucifer',20);
console.log(me.getDescription());

const meNew = new Person('',20);
console.log(meNew.getDescription());
```

Comment: `new Person(undefined, 20)`, but this is not what should be done.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You could just not pass the first value and it would have used the default, the problem was that you are passing in an empty string. So `new Person(,20);` would have worked and outputted Default because undefined would have been substituted for your default.

Comment: new Person(,20); gives an error but new Person(undefined,20); works flawlessly

Comment: yeah, depends on your environment, worked ok in the snippet editor :)

Comment: My bad then, kinda new to es6 classes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have optional arguments before mandatory arguments. You should change the order of your arguments, or use a configuration object:

```
class Person {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.name = options.name || 'Default';
        this.age = options.age || 20;
    }
    getDescription() {
        return `${this.name} is ${this.age} years old`
    }
}

const me = new Person({name: 'Lucifer', age: 20});
console.log(me.getDescription());

const meNew = new Person({age: 20});
console.log(meNew.getDescription());
```